# Can't type text in edit text, but cursor is visible

Tags: android

I'm working with fragments. I've displayed a popup window on button click. Inside popup window, I've added edit text through XML. While running, I cant type in that edit text., but my cursor is visible and blinking.

XML code for the `editText`

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edtTitle" 
         android:layout_width="500dp" 
         android:layout_height="50dp" 
         android:background="#FFFFFF" 
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
         android:gravity="center_vertical" 
         android:hint="Event title" 
         android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
         android:textColor="#000000" 
         android:textSize="20sp" 
         android:textStyle="normal"/>
```

And my activity code:

```
 public void showPopup() {
     LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()); 
     View v = li.inflate(R.layout.popup, null); 
     PopupWindow window = new PopupWindow(v, width, height); 
     edtTitle = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edtTitle);
 }
```

Comment: can you put the xml code for that popup?

Comment: post your code, so we can sort out your problem.

Comment: <EditText 
android:id="@+id/edtTitle"
android:layout_width="500dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:hint="Event title"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"     
ndroid:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="normal"/>

And my code:-

public void showPopup() {
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
View v = li.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
PopupWindow window = new PopupWindow(v, width, height);
edtTitle = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edtTitle); }

Comment: post this in your question. Don't post it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Update your xml code:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edtTitle" 
     android:layout_width="500dp" 
     android:layout_height="50dp" 
     android:background="#FFFFFF" 
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
     android:gravity="center_vertical" 
     android:hint="Event title" 
     android:paddingLeft="10dp"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:focusable="true"
     android:focusableOnTouch="true" 
     android:textColor="#000000" 
     android:textSize="20sp" 
     android:textStyle="normal"/>
```

And also edit your code and check it again:

```
 public void showPopup() {
 LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()); 
 View v = li.inflate(R.layout.popup, null); 
 PopupWindow window = new PopupWindow(v, width, height); 
 Veiw popupView = window.getContentView();
 edtTitle = (EditText) popupView.findViewById(R.id.edtTitle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shah! I tried your code. But no use.. I'm working with fragments. SO, Its not working. If i did the same in Activity, it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a setOnKeyListener in your popup and be sure that you return false if you don't need the event, for example:

```
OnKeyListener listener = new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                //Do something
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the PopupWindow isn't focused, please change the constructor to focusable = true

PopupWindow pop = new PopupWindow(popupView1, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, true);